# PHP is it possible to open a url with a cookie file in some browser after a curl request?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, browser

I am monitoring a website for some opportunities, these opportunities disappear literally in few seconds. I wrote a php code to help me with that which works fine and alert me whenever something becomes available, then I have to open the website, login, enter captchas, navigate few pages, etc etc. By the time I do that the opportunity might have been gone.

So I am wondering if it is possible to open a certain webpage along with cookie files in a browser so that I can get more valuable time to seize the opportunity? I know I can open firefox using `exec`:

```
exec ('firefox -private [url] > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

But from the man page there doesn't seems to exist an option to import cookies. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) by the way.

Comment: If you open the page in private mode firefox disables all cookies, that do not belong to the session you just opened. So you should just open it without the private mode and it should load all cookies automatically.

Comment: I have the cookies stored in a seperate file generated by `curl`, the reason I'm using private mode is so that I don't have to delete cookies everytime I need to open the browser.

Comment: Why do you not want to delete the cookies each time? You could do the following:
1.) Copy your cookies.sqlite file under another name.
2.) Save your cookies from curl as cookies.sqlite
3.) Run firefox
4.) Replace cookies.sqlite with the old one.
-- Since the firefox command stops when the browser is closed you can write all that in a bash script.

Comment: I didn't think of that, it sounds like a good idea, i'll try and see how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

possible? yes, Firefox addons can easily modify cookies, and you could make a firefox addon to communicate with some 127.0.0.1 webserver with php to transfer the cookies... but a much easier to implement solution (which might const you a second or 2 at runtime, but save you time in implementation) would be to simply make ur php script generate the javascript required to transfer the logged-in cookie session from php-curl to your browser, eg

```
$clraw = curl_getinfo ($ch, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST ) [0];
preg_match ( '/PHPSESSID\s+([^\;\s]+)/', $clraw, $matches );
$sessid = $matches [1];
echo 'document.cookie="PHPSESSID=' . $sessid . ';";', PHP_EOL;
```

now it will echo something like `document.cookie="PHPSESSID=v2fuitqmcbb54mc0drspg0l560;";` , which you can just copy & paste to your javascript console, logging you in on refresh... slightly slower than an automatic approach through addons, but trivial to implement (and ofc, if saving those 2 little seconds it take to copy & paste to the javascript is really worth it, invest in making an addon to automate that process)